# How to collect spark dataframe at each executor node?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

My application reads a large parquet file and performs some data extractions to arrive at a smallish spark dataframe object.  All the contents of this dataframe must be present at each executor node for the next phase of the computation.  I know that I can do this by collect-broadcast, as in this pyspark snippet

```
sc = pyspark.SparkContext()
sqlc = HiveContext(sc)

# --- register hive tables and generate spark dataframe
spark_df = sqlc.sql('sql statement')

# collect spark dataframe contents into a Pandas dataframe at the driver
global_df = spark_df.toPandas()

# broadcast Pandas dataframe to all the executor nodes
sc.broadcast(global_df)
```

I was just wondering: is there a more efficient method for doing this?  It would seem that this pattern makes the driver node into a bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you need to do with your small dataframe. If you need to join it with large one, then Spark can optimize such joins broadcasting small dataframe automatically. The max size of dataframe that can be broadcasted is configured by *spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold* option, as described in documentation http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#other-configuration-options